# Find specific sequence of characters combining number and letters using regex in Python pandas

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, contains

I am trying to find all rows in a pandas DataFrame for which the column `col` takes values of the format `1234-XX-YYY`, where `XX` is a placeholder for any two capital letters (A-Z) and `YYY` is a placeholder for any three numbers [0-9].

Here is my code so far

How can I achieve the desired result?

```
df[df['col'].str.contains('^1234-\[A-Z]{2}\[d]{3}', na=False)]
```

Comment: Use `'^1234-[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{3}$'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you escape an open `[` you tell the regex engine to match it as a literal character. If you expect a `-` to appear at some place in the string, you need to add it to the pattern. Also, if you expect uppercase letters to appear, you need `A-Z`, not `a-z`.

Use

```
^1234-[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{3}$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `1234-` - a literal string
- `[A-Z]{2}`  -  two uppercase letters
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[0-9]{3}` - three digits
- `$` - end of string.